# swap hash1 keys with hash2 values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the shortest way to swap `h1` keys with `h2` values:

```
h1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
h2 = {a: 'a1', b: 'b1'}
```

this is the result I want to have after the swap:

```
h1 = {a1: 1, b1: 2, c:3}
```

Comment: The values in `h2` are `String`s, the keys in the result are `Symbol`s, so you are not just swapping `h1`'s keys with `h2`'s values, but also transforming them in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
h2 = {a: 'a1', b: 'b1'}

Hash[h1.map { |k, v| [(h2[k] || k).to_sym ,v] }]
# returns {:a1=>1, :b1=>2, :c=>3}
```

You could also just use `.to_h` instead of `Hash[]`

```
h1.map { |k, v| [(h2[k] || k).to_sym ,v] }.to_h
# returns {:a1=>1, :b1=>2, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
h1 = h1.map{|key, val| [h2.fetch(key,key).to_sym, val]}.to_h
```

Comment: It was added in 2.1 if I remember correctly.. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
h2 = {a: 'a1', b: 'b1'}
h1 = h1.inject({}){ |h, (k, v)| h2.has_key?(k) ? h[h2[k].to_sym] = v : h[k] = v; h }
#=>  {:a1=>1, :b1=>2, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, the solution for live hashes:

```
result = Hash.new { |hash, k| h1[h2.key(k) || k] }
```

Now one might *extend* both `h1` and `h2` and the result will be reflecting new addings (not changes in already addressed keys, though.)

To instantiate this hash with preexisting `h1` and `h2`, one need to execute something like:

```
(h2.values | (h1.keys - h2.keys)).map { |k| [k, result[k]] }.to_h
```

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).